# Where do I find favorite tags in my profile?

Tags: feature-request, tags, profile-page

Where do I find my favourite tags in my profile other than under "Preferences"?

This seems like a petty question I know, but I go to my profile first to act on anything related to my previous answers/comments and (for convenience) I would like to launch into answering new questions by clicking on one of my favourite tags... not be taken to a list of my answers for a given tag.

On the tags section, it seems there is a super-set of every tag that was on any question I have ever answered - most of which don't apply to, or interest me, and its cluttered as all hell. And the favourites section is of course for favourite Questions.

What I had hoped to see under the tags section is those links in the upper right that show you different views etc... and in this case a view of "my Favourite Tags"

Additionally, there is a tags section on the summary page. If the tags section on that could have a view for "My Favourite Tags", that would be ideal.

This is where you get to point out the thing that is staring me right in the face.

EDIT: 
For clarity, Im talking about using favourite tags from my profile page, and preferably from the summary section of it.

Comment: Those are not your favourite tags. Those are, indeed, all the tags from every question or answer you've asked and answered.

Answer (score 8):

Favorite tags are set up manually by you. From the **sites main page** (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/, https://meta.stackoverflow.com and https://unix.stackexchange.com/, **not profile page**), you can find them on the right hand side.

> [image: Favorite Tags location]

---

If you click "Add a favorite tag", you are presented with a simple text box where you can enter the tags you wish to follow and then save. The image below shows that I'm adding [tags](/questions/tagged/tags) and [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) to my favorites

> [image: New tags to favorite]

---

Now these appear on the right hand side for me to follow

> [image: New favorites]

---

If you ever want to edit (or ignore) a set of tags, you can do that by clicking the "edit" link

> [image: Edit favorites]

Comment: Sorry @Andy, Im aware how to add/edit favourite tags, and that I can find my favourite tags in the edit preferences part of the profile. My question is more about how to use those tags from the profile page.

Comment: Was this a feature that was removed?  I can't seem to find any type of control over which tags I have favorited in my profile screen.  I can control them one at a time with the tooltip popup, but not in the way you describe in your answer.

Comment: No it has not. It still works as described. I just went through with a brand new account to make sure

Comment: @r12 It's not in profile page, it's in sites main page, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/